# Free Icon/images

Tags: jquery, html, image, icons

I was wondering if anybody new of a good place to get free icons/images without having to worry about licensing or mentioning the author or bringing in another library. For commercial use as well. The jquery trash icon is perfect for what I'm looking for but it is much to small and cannot be enlarged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For icons, you can try an icon font such as [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). It includes hundreds of icons for free, and since it's a font, you can easily resize or color on the fly. You can link to the fonts and CSS yourself, or just link to the CDN.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. I don't have enough points to upvote but I would if I could.